# MVVM class structure and layout-Calculator Project

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I've recently started learning MVVM, and have learned how to data bind/use Commands/Notify Properties. I'm creating a calculator, and wondered if I have my class structure correct for MVVM and to use WPF properly.

- CaculatorProject - has 10 Buttons(0-9), 4 Buttons(+,-,/,+), and 1 TextBox
- View - contains the Xaml
- ViewModel - 14 `ICommands` for each button, property for the model, and 4 private Math methods
- Model - private variables for current/previous/result values with `INotifyChanged` properties

Does this look correct? Or do I have stuff in the wrong sections?

Comment: You probably don't need 14 I-Commands, I'd make 2 and pass a parameter with each (something like number and operation).

Comment: @KDiTraglia You have a good tutorial on how to do that? Everything i see from search results doesnt click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cut down on a lot of your I-Commands by lumping many of them into a single I-Command that takes a parameter.  For example:

```
<Button Command="YourCommand" 
        CommandParameter="1" 
        Content="1" />
<Button Command="YourCommand" 
        CommandParameter="2" 
        Content="2" />
```

```cs
private void YourCommand_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
     PrintToScreen(e.Parameter.ToString());
}
```